# using tableSorter jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

using jquery tableSorter : https://github.com/christianbach/tablesorter
I have this error

```
 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tablesorter is not a function
```

given that I'm using jquery 1.8 and the js files are correctly loaded

I have table :

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tableau"><thead>
<tr>
<th>col1</th>
 <th>col2</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td> </tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>1</td> </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

and my javascript code  :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                $("table .tableau").tablesorter();  )};
```

Comment: can you provide your code for solutions

Comment: please make sure that you have added the script tag for loading `jquery.tablesorter.js` on your page and also that should be after `jquery.1.8`'s script tag.

Comment: yes it is done . the files are correctly loaded

Comment: it is not working , the problem was that the file was not the correct one

Comment: Try removing the space in the selector: `$("table.tableau")`. Since it is the table that has the class name. The way it is now, it won't select anything because `.tableau` is not a child of the table.